# How to encode positional info in a 2D matrix input to PyTorch

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on a project where the goal is to pass in the current state as a traditional Pandas 2D dataframe converted to 2D numpy array, and the neural network should learn to select the row index of the best action given the features of each row.

So the input dataframe for one state could be something like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user_rating':[10,7,3],'professional_rating':[10,4,1]})
```

[image]

and it would learn to output index 0 since it has the highest rating.
But then the next state could be:

[image]

and it should output index 2 since the 3rd row has the highest rating.

It doesn't seem to work when I flatten out the state and pass it in as a 1D array. Is there any other way of doing this in PyTorch?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide the pytorch code that you have written, the architecture you are using, a sample of the X_train and y_train you are using after preprocessing and the results you are getting. Someone would be able to help you only then. Please read [Minimum Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There are an infinite number of architecture that you can create and another infinite number of problems you can sucessfully solve with them.

Comment: I removed the pytorch, deep-learning tags as they are irrelevant. The question is more `pandas` related. With that said, check out `df.idxmax`